# Annoying redirect preventing me using dashboard of WordPress on localhost

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I can't properly use the WordPress dashboard on locahost because of an annoying redirect. I've logged in but all the files are redirected from...

`http://localhost/wp-admin/` to `http://localhost/wp-admin/localhost/wp-admin/`.

It's really annoying.

I've tried a number of solutions...

1. I've looked in the virtual host. Nothing of use.
2. I've copied .htaccess from live. Then parked .htaccess. No luck.
3. I've parked really-simple-ssl plugin.
4. I've disabled mod-rewrite and enabled it again.

I've no idea where this redirect is coming from. I'm using a remote (live) db and have this set in wp-config...

```
define('WP_HOME','localhost');
define('WP_SITEURL','localhost');
```

I've also tried copying live db to local. no luck.

Comment: You can try to disable all plugins and to check redirect.

Comment: `define('WP_HOME','http://localhost');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://localhost');` does it solve your problem?

Comment: @AmitVerma That should be posted as an answer rather than as a comment. Comments are temporary and cannot be accepted as an answer. There is no mechanism for converting comments to answers, so I cannot do it for you. You will need to copy your comment into the answer box and then delete your comment.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @AmitVerma. I just edited wp-config.php and replace 'localhost' with 'http://localhost/' and it worked.

In other words I added this to wp-config.php...

```
define('WP_HOME','http://localhost/'); 
define('WP_SITEURL','http://localhost/');
```

Comment: I was about to bash up to the wall, thanks man !